# how can we show only subsubsection of a special subsection in table of content?

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

Is there any way that we can restrict table of contents, that show only subsubscetion of for example first subsection?

thanks

I have something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\begin{document}

  \section{Section1}

  some content...

    \subsection{SubSection1}

      some contents ...
        \subsubsection{SubSubsection1.1}
           ...
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection1.2}
           ...
     \subsection{Subsection2}
       some contents ...
         \subsubsection{Subsubsection2.1}
           ...
         \subsubsection{Subsubsection2.2}
           ... 
     \subsection{Subsection3}
       some contents ...
         \subsubsection{Subsubsection3.1}
           ...
         \subsubsection{Subsubsection3.2}
           ...
 \end{document}
```

I want to show only subsubsections1.1 and subsubsection1.2 in table of content below subsection1 and don't want that subsubsections of subsection2 and subsection3.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Package `etoc` should do the trick here.

Comment: This is not a minimal working example. As long as it is unclear which documentclass you are using, nobody can give a straight answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a certain item appearing in ToC then use the starred variant. This applies to other(almost all) document classes.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\begin{document}
\frame{\tableofcontents}

  \section{Section1}
\frame{some content...}
    \subsection{SubSection1}
\frame{some contents ...}
        \subsubsection*{SubSubsection1.1}
        \frame{...}
        \subsubsection{Subsubsection1.2}
        \frame{...}
     \subsection{Subsection2}
     \frame{...}
         \subsubsection*{Subsubsection2.1}
        \frame{...}
         \subsubsection*{Subsubsection2.2}
        \frame{...}
     \subsection{Subsection3}
        \frame{...}
         \subsubsection{Subsubsection3.1}
        \frame{...}
         \subsubsection{Subsubsection3.2}
        \frame{...}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm going to have more than one table of contents and hide subsubsections in different subsections, thank you anyway.